# What is a fast way to find all circle sizes?

Tags: c#, image, algorithm, geometry

Given a completely black and white picture (so the only colors are black or white no shades of grays), there are a lot of different sizes circles on it (in black), what is a fast way to find the center coordinate of the circles and the sizes of the circles and store them as a Dictionary entry? When I mean fast I mean by if I were to call this circle finding function 10 or 20 times per second it wouldn't lag too much. Also I did some researching and found out that I could find the center of a circle or radius by taking three points on the circle, can that help?

[image: Picture]

Comment: I don't think a solution in java is really a duplicate of a question tagged c#.  It might provide good guidance, but a duplicate?

Comment: I also think this is not a duplicate as the linked question describes using a java specific library.

Comment: This is far too broad a question. *What's the fastest way?" can only be measured if you first have something to compare against. What do you have now that isn't performing fast enough for your needs? Without that, this is just "give me teh codez".

Comment: This would make an excellent Code Golf challenge.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to mind is to scan the image pixel by pixel, looking for black pixels.  When you find one, start flood filling.  Once the Flood fill finishes measure the left, right, top, and bottom extents, then derive the center point by dividing by 2.  This assumes that none of the circles overlap.  I'm sure there are probably some more optimized methods that may avoid flooding the entire circle.

**optimization #1:**
Instead of flood filling, when you find the first black pixel, look for adjacent pixels along all 8 neighbors that have at least 1 white neighbor. Continue following those pixels until you hit the first pixel again.  That should give you the outline, from there you can derive the width, height, and center point the same way as in my original answer.

**optimization #2:**  If the circles have a minimum size you don't have to scan pixel by pixel.  You can scan horizontal and vertical lines spaced by the minimum size looking for black pixels.

Comment: Is there a faster to achieve this? My program will have to call this function at least 10 times per second on a timer sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot avoid having to check all the white pixels, so the algorithm's complexity will always be O(width*height). However, you definitely don't need to check all the black pixels.

Once you find an edge of a circle you can just walk horizontally until next edge, and then vertically until another edge. With these 3 points on the edge you can build a rectangle which will have the same center as the circle. Then just walk vertically or horizontally to find the circle's radius.

[image: rectangle inside a circle will have same center as the circle]

Comment: Your answer calculates the height, width, and center of the circle more efficiently than mine. Nicely done.  If there is a minimum circle size, I think I have an optimization that avoids scanning all the white pixels.

Comment: You also can draw just two sides of your rectangle, and with pitagoras you will get the radius.

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple ray tracer that scans your space left to right, top to bottom, pixel by pixel. When you hit a black pixel you have some work to do. Here is an algorithm.

1. while current pixel is white, advance to the next one (left to right, or next row of pixels)
2. when you hit a black pixel, move downward in a vertical line until you hit a white pixel. That's your diameter, you use that to calculate your circle size (whatever you mean by size). To mark this circle as *visited*, color the perimeter in say green (simple edge detection algorithm); this way, if you hit a green pixel first as you cruise along, keep cruising in the black circles until you hit the green on the other symmetric side of the circle. Therefore, no need for a complete flood-fill algorithm and you get a away with calculating size or skipping *visited* circles in a fraction of the cost needed by the flood-fill algorithm.

Note 1. The screens are rasterized, which means that the first pixel you hit is not necessarily the top one, it could be one of the ones to the right of it so you have to do a bit navigating right and left because of antialiasing to determine the right top one and shoot down from it.

Note 2. If your circles overlap, say so and lets dump this algorithm and think of something else :-)